# Changing tomcat 6 to tomcat 7 Giving error

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception, tomcat7, tomcat6

My application running well in tomcat 6 with this connection variable

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Travel","root","root");
```

I have already tried many places to solve this but I couldn't find solution. But in tomcat 7 when I try to use connection variable it return `Null pointer Exception`.
Is there any way to change it in connection file?

Comment: i dont think this is a issue with tomcat

Comment: But i im changing only tomcat6 to tomcat,all other things are same as previous. all static pages ar working  fine only connection problem...

Comment: Thanks @jWeaver for make my question understandable

Comment: have you included mysql.jar in libs folder

Comment: i have settled classpath variable of mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hads similar issue Tomcat7 with mysql-connector-java-5.1.26 that put in both my $CATALINA_HOME/lib and WEB-INF/lib, just in case. But it wouldn't find it until  use either one of these two statements before getting the connection:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ());

OR

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

then followup with removing mysql-connector-java-5.1.26 from $CATALINA_HOME/lib and the connection still works.